# How to set the "collate" property of a Printer

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am running Ms-Access reports through my application in vba. When a user wishes to print a report, my application exposes its own print dialog to choose the content and format of the report. In some cases the user may decide to create multiple copies of the report. The report is generating tickets, sometimes 4-up. Say the user wants to create 25 copies of each of 24 tickets. He/she would select the 25 copies in the custom dialog and my code would set the copies property of the Access Printer object to 25.

In this case it would be desirable to print the items with collating. After cutting the paper into 4s and stacking appropriately, all copies of each ticket would be together. Does the access Printer object support the collate property? I cannot seem to find it in the dialog.

If not, is there an alternative Windows dialog I should try?

Comment: I don't know if that printer attribute can be programmatically controlled, but might be able to print records in an order so that when 'cut and stacked', they will be correctly collated. Review http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=73256

Comment: Thanks for help about cut and stacked.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the Msoft Access95 Developer's Handbook (Paul Litwin, Ken Getz, et al) in Chapter 10 about controlling printers.

There is a prtDevMode Property that belongs to a Form or a Report. This is a 92 byte character array. It is still current - I checked in Microsoft Support Internet page and it provided definitions and samples that applies for Access Office 365, Access 2016, Access 2013, Access 2010 and Access 2007.

It would be best to check there for instructions. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/PrtDevMode-Property-F87EEBDC-A13E-484A-83ED-2E2BEEB9D699

Comment: Thanks for updating the link. The original link was the one I was looking at when I wrote the answer.